# Why interrupts can help to increase the efficiency of a user program that contains many I/O operations?

Tags: cpu

I am reading Computer Architecture & Organization by William Stallings to understand I/O operations. I get the general mechanisms of how interrupts are handled in computer systems, but the results of interrupts improving the efficiency of user programs with many I/O programs is kinda counter intuitive. As from what I know, it seems that the computer tends to be more efficient if it is dedicated to one task. So can anyone help explain more clearly why interrupts can increase the efficiency of a user program that contains many I/O operations?
Any kind of advice is welcomed

Comment: Do you mean "7.4 Interrupt-driven I/O"?

Comment: @tevemadar yes, that is what I meant

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O

Comment: But which particular part? The first two paragraphs already describe 1) waiting in a busy loop is inefficient, as the program just burns CPU cycles checking some flag "is it ready? is it ready? is it ready?", and 2) if the program has something else to do, it could progress with that instead. Even if the entire system has absolutely nothing else to do than waiting, it's better to rely on a hardware interrupt, so the program can issue some HALT or similar instruction and the CPU just sleeps afterwards.